# IOException: Not enough quota is available to process this command

Tags: java, ioexception

I use Netbeans (8.1) to test small code snippets, but today all of a sudden, I have been getting an `IOException`, even with a simple "Hello World" program.

I found similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584619/mysterious-not-enough-quota-is-available-to-process-this-command-in-winrt-port), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640239/java-lang-error-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command-when) but none seem to solve my issue.

My memory usage is at ~12%, and it's an 8GB machine.

> java.io.IOException: Not enough quota is available to process this
>   command   at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)     at
>   org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:557)  at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.usages.BuildArtifactMapperImpl.copyFile(BuildArtifactMapperImpl.java:462)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.usages.BuildArtifactMapperImpl.copyRecursively(BuildArtifactMapperImpl.java:541)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.usages.BuildArtifactMapperImpl.copyRecursively(BuildArtifactMapperImpl.java:534)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.usages.BuildArtifactMapperImpl.copyRecursively(BuildArtifactMapperImpl.java:534)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.usages.BuildArtifactMapperImpl.ensureBuilt(BuildArtifactMapperImpl.java:279)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.TranslateClassPath.translateEntry(TranslateClassPath.java:145)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.TranslateClassPath.translate(TranslateClassPath.java:107)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.TranslateClassPath.execute(TranslateClassPath.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Don't use an IDE tag just because you use that IDE. Unless the issue has something directly to do with it, [tag:netbeans] is irrelevant.

Comment: @user207421 well - it only happened using Netbeans for me, not on Eclipse nor IntelliJ so that's why I tagged it.

Answer (score -1):

Despite the fact the error message never specified, but the error code was `0x80070718`.

Which led to the [solution](http://blog.coultard.com/2012/01/fix-windows-error-0x80070718-not-enough.html):

> Open Control Panel -> Sync Centre -> Manage Offline Files -> Disk
>   Usage -> Change Limits

Within this location, I only had mere bytes left in my offline files.