# visual studio crashes randomly devenv KERNELBASE.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2013, threadpool, richtext, win32-process

My Visual Studio crashes randomly. Event Viewer shows the following error

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.40629.0, time
>   stamp: 0x5590c8a4
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.15063.674, time stamp: 0x6d16dd24
>
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
>
> Fault offset: 0x000eb872
>
> Faulting process id: 0x3b00
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d34ecf7a049150
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: xxxxxxxx-867c-4c54-b259-c28a7b9d8151
>
> Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I have tried running devenv /SAFEMODE command at (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE)

but still it keeps occuring and sometimes a dialog box also appears "**not enough storage available**"

> Application: devenv.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D)

**Activity Log**

(0x80004005): Not enough storage is available to process this command

at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d)

at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)

at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(HwndSourceParameters parameters)

at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource..ctor(HwndSourceParameters parameters)

at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.PopupSecurityHelper.BuildWindow(Int32 x, Int32 y, Visual placementTarget, Boolean transparent, HwndSourceHook hook, AutoResizedEventHandler handler)

at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.BuildWindow(Visual targetVisual)

at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateWindow(Boolean asyncCall)

at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)

at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)

at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)

at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.MouseTrackingQuickInfoPresenter.Render()

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.IntellisenseSessionStack.OnSessionPresenterChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.IntellisenseSession.RaisePresenterChanged()

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Recalculate()

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoSession.Start()

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.QuickInfoBroker.TriggerQuickInfo(ITextView textView, ITrackingPoint triggerPoint, Boolean trackMouse)

at Microsoft.Html.Editor.HtmlQuickInfoController.OnMouseHover(Object sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e)

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()

### UPDATE

My Application runs for once or twice in **safemode** then even that exits. When trying to restart visual studio, it fails. Then event viewer or cmd prompt do not work and i have to restart my machine to make something work.

### UPDATE 2

Looks like [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/620588/system-componentmodel-win32exception-0x80004005-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543956/how-to-debug-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/41544029#41544029) is my issue. Now How do i use Dispatcher in my code?

```
public string ConvertRtfToHtml(string rtfText)
    {

        try
        {
            var thread = new Thread(ConvertRtfInSTAThread);                
            var threadData = new ConvertRtfThreadData { RtfText = rtfText };
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start(threadData);

            try
            {
                thread.Join();
            }
            catch(ThreadStateException e){
                logger.Error("ThreadStateException " + e.Message);
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException e) {
                logger.Error("ThreadInterruptedException " + e.Message);
            }                


            return threadData.HtmlText;

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            logger.Error("ConvertRtfToHtml: " + e.InnerException.Message);
            return "Error";
        }

    }
```

the **ConvertRtfToHtml** is being called from within a loop
the **ConvertRtfInSTAThread** uses a RichTextBox control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lots of trial and errors i found the root cause was [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/620588/system-componentmodel-win32exception-0x80004005-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047437/using-dispatcher-with-thread/47089378#47089378) is my implementation.