# Identifying Component causing an error

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi 2010 project I am trying to work with. I am getting some errors with the Delphi application itself from what I can tell. When I click on the menu option Project, and select Options, I receive the following error: Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000. IF I do the exact same thing a second time I receive the error Access violation at address 2099331F1 in module 'coreide140bpl'. Read of address 00000000. When I Right Click the project and select Option, I receive the same error message.

Some other posts suggested removing and re-installing all third party components, but I have no idea how to do that, and from what I understand the menu option I need to use to find the 3rd party components is the one that is erroring out.

Comment: Did the project used to work? Do other (or new) projects work ok?  Do you have backups of the project?  Do older versions work?  Have you installed any third-party components recently?

Comment: Could be that your project is corrupt. If you know its structure maybe you can start a new project, then add all the forms an units from your existing project to it.

Comment: I am new on the project, but yes it used to work, at some point. I tried another project and received even more errors. Called (Embarcadero) Delphi and they suggested starting with the command line switch to rest user preferences, still the same errors.

Answer (score 7):

What I would do in a case like this is open up a second instance of Delphi, and use the `Run->Attach To Process` menu command to attach the debugger to the first instance of the IDE. Then reproduce the crash in the first copy, and have a look at the stack trace in the second copy.  Look at what packages and units are involved, and that should give you some idea of what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Here is what I got attaching to the process: 
Module Load: bordbk140N.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $03C20000. Process bds.exe (3136)
Thread Start: Thread ID: 2752. Process bds.exe (3136)
Thread Exit: Thread ID: 2752. Process bds.exe (3136)
Thread Exit: Thread ID: 4168. Process bds.exe (3136)
Thread Exit: Thread ID: 4196. Process bds.exe (3136)
First chance exception at $76B4C41F. Exception class EOutOfResources with message
'The parameter is incorrect.
'.
Process bds.exe (3136)

Comment: All right. That doesn't look like an access violation, but that's a place to start at least.  Have a look at the stack trace.  I can't really help you too much because I'm not familiar with your setup, but take a look at what the system was doing at the time and you should get a pretty good idea of what's going on.

Comment: I believe this is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507853/system-error-code-8-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command