# java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: java, windows, nio

I have to copy images (4-6 MB each) periodically (each 8 seconds) into one folder. When a files count in the target folder reaches circa 320 files, an error is thrown. And if I restart an application, **another** circa 320 files are copied before an error is thrown again (so it is independent on a files count in a target directory):

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: X:\src\from.jpg ->
>   X:\target\to.jpg: **Not enough storage is available to process this
>   command** 
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
>   at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:205) at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
>   at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)

I'm using `Files.copy(f.toPath(), t.toPath())` to copy the file.

I think a problem si related to [System Error. Code: 8. Not enough storage is available to process this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507853/system-error-code-8-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command) .

Is it possible to somehow clean used resources to avoid this Exception?

Comment: How do you name your files ? Do you overwrite the files ?

Comment: No, I have to keep all files so every filename is unique.

Comment: Well it seems that you just dont have enough space on your HD. Either make some or write your files on a different location.

Comment: I have many free space. As I write above when I rerun my app, it writes 300 files again. It is not related to disk space.

Comment: How much free space do you have then ? If the file names does not change, then it just overwrite the old one but once it get to actually create a new one, it crashes.

Comment: We are hitting this issue at a customer site (one out of many, many sites).  I don't have anything to suggest at this time, just letting you know that you aren't alone.