# Prevent pop-up windows launched from named pipe

Tags: pipe, adb, freepascal

I have a cmd running 'via' a pipe, created like this:

```
  console:=TProcess.Create(Nil);
  console.Commandline:='cmd.exe';
  console.Options:=[poUsePipes,poNoConsole,poStderrToOutPut];
  console.CurrentDirectory:=apppath+'data\';
  console.ShowWindow:=swoHIDE;
  console.execute;
```

Now, my problem is that I'm using cmd to send commands to android device through adb (which is another command line tool).
While cmd window itself is hidden, each adb call creates new console window which shortly after closes automatically.
How do I hide all those windows altogether?

Comment: Are you sure this is Delphi?

Comment: adb client is very simple. it can be implemented in under 100 lines of code. and if you ever programmed sockets it should take you under an hour from scratch.

Comment: Why use cmd? Why not create an adb process? Why the middle man?

Comment: Let's say I want to do other things with cmd besides calling adb like copy 
a file? And I tried that in the first place :P Didn't work, not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you execute `adb.exe`, it needs to start a new instance of `cmd.exe` if not already being called by `cmd.exe`.  So, for what you are attempting, simply run `cmd.exe` *one time* and keep the session open, and then write commands to it (like ADB commands) over the existing STDIN pipe using the `TProcess.Input` property.

Better still, you could implement the ADB protocol directly in your own code, [communicating over a TCP/USB connection to the device itself](https://github.com/cstyan/adbDocumentation).  Then you wouldn't need to run `adb.exe` at all.

Or, to make things a bit simpler, you could run `adb.exe` as a local server and then [communicate with it over a TCP connection](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/OVERVIEW.TXT) instead of through `cmd.exe`.  This is what `adb.exe` does internally when it is run as a client.

Comment: the doc you linked to is describing *adb server to adb daemon* communication. In my comment I suggested to implement the *adb client* - for which the OP would need to implement even simpler *adb client to adb server* protocol

Comment: @AlexP. yes, what I linked to is the protocol used to communicate with the device itself, then you don't need to run ADB at all. But, if you want to make things simpler, you could run the local ADB server and then communicate with it instead. I added a link to that documentation.

Comment: I thought I'm doing exactly that, 'cmd' TProcess is created once and adb commands are sent through console.Input.WriteBuffer but this results in more console windows popping up as stated in initial question. One way I've found was creating new cmd TProcess with adb as parameter for each calll but this resulted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507853/system-error-code-8-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command after few hours (at least I think that's the cause). I'll look into alternate means to communicate with adb/device but it doesn't answer the question per se?

Comment: @laggyluk: it has been awhile since I last used ADB, but I don't remember it behaving the way you describe. Executing ADB commands via a single CMD process should not be running new consoles or displaying any pop-up windows. If you run CMD manually, can you reproduce the same issue? Can you provide a [mcve] showing your ADB commands via `TProcess`?

Comment: Ok, hope didn't forget any unit. In any case compiled project with adb binary is in bin.zip https://github.com/laggyluk/adbConsoleTest

Comment: fixed with removing poNoConsole from TProcess startup options. Feel free to edit your answer as it's almost correct :P