# Pandas installation fails with "OSError: [WinError8] Not enough storage is available to process this command"

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I was trying to install pandas using this command:

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

Installation starts initially but then goes all red and returns this error:

> Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError8] Not enough storage is available to process this command
> --- Logging error ---

I don't think it's a memory issue because I checked usage and it was at a normal level.

I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 7.

Any suggestions on how to fix it??

Comment: "*Not enough storage*" is not about operative memory, it's about permanent memory, i.e. disk room.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507853/system-error-code-8-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command).

Comment: No chance the actual problem is physical memory, both partitions have loads of space left.. I'll check this out k33da, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Eureka! I'm posting solution in case anyone encounters the same problem in the future.**

After hours of trying a lot of different solutions I have finally succeed even though I still don't know what was the source of this problem.

To install pandas in case of facing error while downloading using `pip` command first **download manually .whl files** of pandas from PyPI website:

https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files

Copy it to the folder that is used as your path in cmd console- don't change name of the file.

In cmd console use:

`python -m pip install fullnameofthedownloadedfile.whl --no-deps`

Use `--no-deps` as it's very likely that automatically downloaded dependencies will encounter similar errors during downloading as pandas- you will install them manually instead.

Once this is finished repeat process for `numpy` and `dateutil` and any other packages that might be required.

What a relief!!! Happy coding;)